# Limit the number of Responses in Google Geocoding API

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Is there any way I can Limit my Number of Responses from the Google Servers in the my Geocoding Request. ?
I have my API Call as : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=27.7041,85.3226&key=[mykey]&result_type=political